# can't load tileset cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying Ray Wenderlich's tutorials for making a tile based 
[game] (http://www.raywenderlich.com/29458/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-2-x)

When I try to load my .tmx file it tells me it can't find the tileset file.
I've looked into the problem and found this [solution] (https://iphonedevsdk.vanillaforums.com/forum/iphone-sdk-game-development/81383-cocos2d-and-tiled.html)

Yet when I look into my .tmx file, the file reference is only the filename. The tileset file is in the same folder as the .tmx file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map SYSTEM "http://mapeditor.org/dtd/1.0/map.dtd">
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="50" height="50" tilewidth="32"   tileheight="32">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="tmw_desert_spacing" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" spacing="1" margin="1">
  <image source="tmw_desert_spacing.png" width="265" height="199"/>
 </tileset>
  <layer name="Tile Layer 1" width="50" height="50">
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
    H4sIAAAAAAAAA+3DAQkAAAwEoUvy/WMux0DBVVNVVVVVVVVVVdXnD6vDAUcQJwAA
   </data>
  </layer>
 </map>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: check that filename is identical, including case. Also doublecheck the tileset is added to the (correct) target

Comment: @LearnCocos2D already checked the file names and they are the same. When you ask if the tileset is added to the correct target, what are you referring to? In my code I use the following
CCTMXTiledMap *tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"otherOne.tmx"]; which is the name of the tilemap.

Comment: make sure tmw_desert_spacing.png is placed in same folder.

Comment: @Guru already triple checked that. I've actually been going through the parser, and I think that the way that tilemap encodes its xml tags is different from before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a combination of several things. Though I included the file in the path, I still had to add the .png to the copy bundle resources in the Build Phases under project resources. After doing that, I had to change the file path to remove the path. After that it worked